# PHP count() returns 2 separate values

Tags: php, count

So I have a function that selects all the columns where something = something, and then I return a variable that fetches all `$var->fetchAll();`.
I made that function so I can count whatever it's returning and it almost worked as expected.

That function returns (using var_dump for debug):

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "18" [0]=> string(2) "18" } [1]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "19" [0]=> string(2) "19" } } 2

array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "20" [0]=> string(2) "20" } } 1
```

it returns this separately so when I count() this it returns 2 and 1 separately instead of 3... any idea why ?

Here is the code I made:

```
$ticketsRes = $objDatabase->getMemberResponsesById($playerTicket->ticketid);

var_dump($ticketsRes);

$group = array();

foreach ( $ticketsRes as $ticket ) {
    $group[$ticket['id']][] = $ticket;
}

echo count($group); //returns 2 and 1 instead of 3
```

Comment: Yeah, you have an array with two entries (index `0` and index `1`), and another one with one entry.at index `0`. So everything works as predicted.

Comment: Any way to concatenate them ?

Comment: Sure, why could'nt you? Use `array_merge()`

Comment: It still returns 2 and 1 instead of 3.. since I am not merging 2 arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Count only conuts the top level of the array, nested arrays mean you have to do

```
count ( $array, true )
```

For example it even says `array(2) {..} array(1){...}` from your `var_dump`, which tells me right there that I would expect `2` and `1` from `count($array)`.  Besides I can tell it's multi-dimensional arrays just looking at them.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

> int count ( mixed $array_or_countable [, int $mode = COUNT_NORMAL ] )
>
> mode: If the optional mode parameter is set to COUNT_RECURSIVE (or 1), count() will recursively count the array. This is particularly useful for counting all the elements of a multidimensional array.

The little known second parameter allows you to count "recursively" by setting it to 1 or COUNT_RECURSIVE, but in PHP true is the same thing as 1 ( so lazy me just uses that )

Right who knew count has 2 inputs, ( << this guy ).  I also know you can do isset on multiple items `isset($item1, $item2, ... )` ha ha.  I also know your output is from var dump,  yea me...  ( I write too much code, almost got divorced when I was learning PHP, got a bit addicted to it)